# How to get the exact value after multiplying and dividing a BigDecimal in java

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

```
import java.math.*;

public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){

BigDecimal initialValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(193);
BigDecimal divider = BigDecimal.valueOf(3);
BigDecimal result = initialValue.divide(divider, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(initialValue + " / " + divider+" = "+result);
BigDecimal retriveInitialValue = result.multiply(divider);
System.out.println(result + " * " + divider+" = "+retriveInitialValue);

}
}
```

Output i am getting
193 / 3 = 64.33

64.33 * 3 = 192.99

What i Expect 
193 / 3 = 64.33

64.33 * 3 = 193

Comment: If you round your interim results you can't expect, that the final result will be what you expect!

Comment: Why do you expect `64.33 * 3` to equal `193`?

Comment: @GabrielNegut Sir,my intention  is to get initial value.plz help

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you can't, because dividing 193 by 3 without rounding will give you an `ArithmeticException`, as the result contains an infinitely repeating decimal. Once you round, you can't be guaranteed to get back the original result, as you lost some precision.

Comment: I can't decide whether this question is a thinly veiled trolling attempt or not, I'm leaning towards the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
org.jscience.mathematics.number.FloatingPoint initialValue =  org.jscience.mathematics.number.FloatingPoint.valueOf("145.123456789");
org.jscience.mathematics.number.FloatingPoint divideWith =   org.jscience.mathematics.number.FloatingPoint.valueOf("3");
org.jscience.mathematics.number.FloatingPoint result = initialValue.divide(divideWith); 
System.out.println(result.doubleValue() );
org.jscience.mathematics.number.FloatingPoint finalResult = result.times(divideWith);
System.out.println(finalResult.doubleValue() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get this result, until you implement some `class` Rational, which will contain numerator and denominator. Every calculation is made with some precision. Also, you may round it to get the close integer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
BigDecimal retriveInitialValue = result.multiply(divider);
```

... to ...

```
BigDecimal retriveInitialValue = result.multiply(divider).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

**Output**

```
64.33 * 3 = 193
```

Comment: Sir , but if initialValue is 194 , it is not working

Comment: @latifmohammadkhan sorry, typo in my answer. I just fixed the rounding mode now.

Comment: Sir if initialValue is 194.65 , it is not working. :(